# Saving Php variable to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Im having a issue saving data i have stored into a variable into mysql database. I am able to connect to the database no issue but when i run the code i get a blank page and nothing save to the database.

This is the variable that i want to store into the table "links" and into the column "title"

```
$title="breakingbad";
```

Here is my full code.

```
<?php
$host="yourhosthere";
$username="yourusername";
$password="yourpassword";
$database="your database";
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$title="breakingbad";
$query = "INSERT INTO links (title) VALUES('$title')");
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing how your database table is set up, I think the extra parentheses right before the semi-colon on this line is causing a fatal error and you probably have error messages turned off:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO links (title) VALUES('$title')");
```

Comment: Well spotted. Didnt even bother to really look at the code :) Debugging without error reporting sucks )

Comment: Also tried to remove the extra parentheses still see blank page and nothing saved to db.

Comment: I apologize that was the issue i had a syntax issue elsewhere after i did what you said thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A blank page means you dont have error reporting on. This means you are not seeing the correct error message.

Add:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

to the top of your page. This will show you the correct error.

You also have a @ infront of mysql_select_db, which also surpesses errors. Remove that.

(Also switch to mysqli_ functions/objects instead of using deprectated mysql_.

When you did the above you probably will be able to fix your problem. If not, add the actual error message.

Comment: I did what you said but i still see a blank page. I fixed your error here to `ini_set('display_errors', true);`